# How to find the sum of all prime numbers less than 1000 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby. I want to know how to get the sum of all prime numbers below 1000. Code below prints out all the prime numbers between 1 to 1000.

```
require 'prime'

p = Prime.new
(1..1000).each do |n|
  q = p.next()
  puts "#{n}: #{q}" 
end
```

How do I find the sum of those prime numbers. Appreciate your help

Comment: `Prime.each(1000).inject :+`

Answer (score 1):

```
Prime.each(1000).inject :+
# => 76127
```

Answer (score 1):

> Prime.new is obsolete. Now Prime has the default instance and you can access it as Prime.instance.
>
> For convenience, each instance method of Prime.instance can be accessed as a class method of Prime.

So, your refactored prime printing code would be:

```
Prime.each(1000).with_index { |p, i| puts "#{i+1}: #{p}" }
#=>
1: 2
2: 3
3: 5
4: 7
5: 11
...
...
```

And to finding the **sum**:

```
Prime.each(1000).reduce(:+)
#=> 76127
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
Prime.each(1000).inject :+
```